# How to throw custom exception in php while parsing csv files?

Tags: php, csv, exception

I'm writing php code to parse a csv file. I have to validate the basic data type for all the fields in the csv fileds and should throw an instance of a CsvParserException if there is any broken data in the csv file. I've given a generic exception but I want to give a custom exception which is an instance of CsvParserException.

Below is my code. I'm not sure how to to properly handle this.

```
<?php

namespace app;

class CsvParser{

    public function parse() {
        $row = 1;
        $flag = true;
        if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
                echo $num;
                $row++;
                if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; } // this is to skip the first line
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    echo "data[0] is = ". $data[0] . " data[c] is = ". $data[$c]. " <br />\n";
                    if(!((isset($data[0])) && (is_numeric($data[0])))) {
                        throw new \Exception('Id is not valid');
                    }
                    if(!((isset($data[1])) && (is_string($data[1])))) {
                        throw new \Exception('This is not a valid string. ');
                    }
                    if(!((isset($data[2])) && (is_string($data[2])))) {
                        throw new \Exception('This is not a valid string. ');
                    }
                    $date = strtotime($data[3]); 
                    $splitData = explode('|', $data[4]);
                    foreach($splitData as $value) {
                        if(!((isset($value)) && (is_numeric($value)))) {
                            throw new \Exception('Integers is not valid');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: The manual [Extending Exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

Comment: `CsvParserException` is not a PHP built-in, so you'll just have to define it yourself.

Comment: Note that your checks here are _inside_ the foreach loop that iterates over the columns, so you're performing every check multiple times for each column.

Comment: Also, `fgetcsv()` will always return strings. If the values are numeric you'll get string `"123"` and even if they're empty you'll get the empty string `""` -- so the `is_string()` check will _never_ fail.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I was able to define a custom exception and it's working for me. Thank you for the valuable inputs.